# Push to / Update an Array in React JS State

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm fairly new to working with React JS and I'm having a problem pushing items to an array that's part of the components state.

What I'm intending to happen is that when the component mounts the state (allDays array) is updated to list every day in the current month and the next two months. I'm just getting an empty array though. I've checked the loop and that's outputting the dates, they're just not being pushed to the array.

My current JavaScript is:

```
class CalendarDisplay extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { allDays: [] };
    }

    findDays = () => {

        var self = this;

        var currentDate = new Date();
        var mFormat = currentDate.getFullYear() + '-' + (currentDate.getMonth() + 1) + '-01';

        var startBookingDate = moment(mFormat);
        var endBookingDate = moment().add(2, 'M').endOf('month');

        var currentDate = moment(startBookingDate);

        while (currentDate <= endBookingDate) {

            self.setState({
                allDays: self.state.allDays.concat(moment(currentDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
            });

            currentDate = moment(currentDate).add(1, 'days');

        }

    }

    componentDidMount = () => {

        this.findDays();
        console.log(this.state.allDays);

    }

    render = () => {
        return (
            <div>Please See the Console Log</div>
        )
    }

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <CalendarDisplay />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Here's a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2jxye74z/) of the issue.

I've been reading through the other answers on Stack Overflow and they don't seem to work with this issue. I'm currently trying to use concat technique without success.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
self.setState({
                allDays: self.state.allDays.concat(moment(currentDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
            });
```

To (editted as per comments)

```
 self.state.allDays.push(moment(currentDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

you need to push the values to the array not concat them.

See [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2jxye74z/7/)

Comment: Does this actually work?
I thought `Array.push` returned the length of the array, and mutated the array, rather than returning a new one.

Comment: @stinodes it does work, you can test it in the jsfiddle

Comment: The thing is that it would also even if you removed the `setState`, because you are just mutating the array that's in state rather that actually setting state. If you were to do this anywhere else, it would not even trigger a rerender (or trigger it with the array's length as `allDays`' value).

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2jxye74z/7/ .
It just logs the return value of `push` (which is the length), but it never does setState.

Answer (score 3):

Perfomance-wise, updating state too many times is not a good pattern. Not to mention that it is going to trigger `render` a lot.

My suggestion is to keep all values in a temporary variable and then update your state only once.

```
let days = []
while (currentDate <= endBookingDate) {
   days = [...days, moment(currentDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')]
   currentDate = moment(currentDate).add(1, 'days')
}

this.setState({ allDays: days })
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll give this a try

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can't update the state like that. You should fully build the end array and then update the state. Another benefit of doing it that way is that you will only update the state once (instead of 30/31 times).

```
findDays = () => {
    var month = [];
    var self = this;

    var currentDate = new Date();
    var mFormat = currentDate.getFullYear() + '-' + (currentDate.getMonth() + 1) + '-01';

    var startBookingDate = moment(mFormat);
    var endBookingDate = moment().add(2, 'M').endOf('month');

    var currentDate = moment(startBookingDate);

    while (currentDate <= endBookingDate) {

        month.push(moment(currentDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));

        currentDate = moment(currentDate).add(1, 'days');

    }

    self.setState({ allDays: month );

}
```